# Pin OS X Terminal Window (Always on top in MacOS Yosemite)

Tags: macos, mac

How do I pin Mac OS X terminal window on top of all other opened windows (always visible)?

I have Mac OS X Yosemite.

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 9):

After much research on how to get a terminal to type into no matter which window I am in on Mac, even it was full screen or split screen, this is how you can get it.

[image]

iTerm2 go to Preferences

[image]

Click on "Create a Dedicated..." > Assign a hotkey and ensure you check the box, "Floating window".

Note: Add iterm2 in your startup at login.

Comment: It would stay on top but it would disappear as soon as you click out of it, is this right?

Answer (score 3):

To me, the best solution is to install [iterm2](http://www.iterm2.com). It's just a minute! After that open term2, go to "Window" top menu and choose "Keep Afloat". As easy as that! And a lot of users recommend iterm2 as the best Mac OS X terminal alternative, for example: [Lifehacker.com - The best terminal emulator for Mac OS X](http://lifehacker.com/5857046/the-best-terminal-emulator-for-mac-os-x)

Comment: You don't have 'afloat' or another app installed? my ITerm2 (v2.1.4) doesn't have a "Keep Afloat" option in the Window menu. I'm on OS X 10.11.1.

Comment: Yes, not everyone has [Afloat](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/22237/afloat) installed. And Afloat is supposed to work with any Cocoa app including stock terminal.

Comment: Yikes! last update to Afloat was about 5 years ago and it only claims to work with 10.7 - that's mighty stale. See this post: http://www.perfectlyrandom.org/2015/01/31/always-on-top-in-macos-yosemite/

Answer (score 1):

There's a Github repository called [EasySIMBL](https://github.com/norio-nomura/EasySIMBL) that will do exact this for you. I found that in [this article](http://www.perfectlyrandom.org/2015/01/31/always-on-top-in-macos-yosemite/), which also walks you through installation and the basics of the program.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! I saw this article (googled it). The solution is not stable. EasySIMBL stops working very often. Is there any other solutions?